# Force Rails to assign nil value also using simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I have a use case in a web page, in which I need to have "nil" value also, besides true and false.
I have implemented it like bellow but when I choose "unchecked" in GUI it always jumps to 'Yes' (true).
Is there anyway to force Rails to assign nil value also ?

Code:

f.input :confirmed, label: 'Confirmed', as: :radio_buttons, collection: [[ true, "Yes" ], [ false, "No" ], [ nil, "unchecked"]], label_method: :second, value_method: :first, selected: [ nil, 'unchecked' ]

Comment: are you sure you do not have a default set for the column in the database? Can you post the params that are being passed by the form and the other relevant code e.g. controller and model as needed?

Answer (score 0):

You can try use [collection_radio_buttons](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_radio_buttons):

```rb
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons(:confirmed, [[true, 'Yes'], [false, 'No'], [nil, 'unchecked']], :first, :second,{ checked: [nil, 'unchecked'] }) do |b| %>
  <% b.label do %>
    <%= b.radio_button %> <%= b.text %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried it but I have the same issue. In the database 'nil' value is not saved. When pick the 'unchecked' I press the submit button it gives me the success message but I if I search in the database the 'nil' value is not saved, the value that is saved is 'true'.